# max.col with NA removal

Tags: r, max, na

I'm looking to find the columns of matrix row-maxima while ignoring NAs. E.g.,

```
set.seed(1)
a <- matrix(runif(15), ncol=3)
a[a<.3] <- NA
a[5,] <- NA
```

That is:

```
> a
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,]    NA 0.898    NA 
[2,] 0.372 0.945    NA
[3,] 0.573 0.661 0.687
[4,] 0.908 0.629 0.384
[5,]    NA    NA    NA
```

The row maxima, ignoring NAs, can be obtained using `max`:

```
> apply(a, 1, max, na.rm=T)
[1] 0.898 0.945 0.687 0.908  -Inf
```

I'm looking for the column positions of these maxima, but `max.col` only works for rows without any NAs.

```
> max.col(a, ties.method="first")
[1] NA NA  3  1 NA
```

How could I find the columns of (first) maximizers for the rows with some non-missing values? I.e., something like:

```
[1]  2  2  3  1 NA
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We `replace` the 'NA' with `-Inf` in 'a' and apply the `max.col` on that.

```
v1 <- max.col(replace(a, is.na(a), -Inf), ties.method="first")
```

But, this will return 1 for the last row which have all NAs.  To return NA, we can multiply it with the NA converted negated (`!`) `rowSums` of logical matrix (`!is.na(a)`).

```
v1 * NA^!rowSums(!is.na(a))
#[1]  2  2  3  1 NA
```

EDIT: Changed the `replace`ment from 0 to -Inf based on @Frank's comment

---

As the OP was using `apply`, `which.max` can return the column index

```
apply(a, 1, function(x) which.max(x)[1])
#[1]  2  2  3  1 NA
```

Or

```
sapply(apply(a, 1, which.max), `length<-`, 1)
#[1]  2  2  3  1 NA
```

Comment: I would upvote the first option after the edit as the most transparent.

Comment: @user3605620  Where do you want to change?  I already made the changes according to Franks' comment.