# Index of an R data.table column with the smallest element

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with missing values where some rows only contain NA's. The `data.table` is actually a subset of columns of a larger `data.table` so I'd like to avoid dropping all-NA rows. I want to find an elegant way to *find the index of the column with the smallest element in each row and add the resulting array as a new column to the `data.table`*. For all-NA rows, I want an NA result. Here is an inelegant way to do so:

```
> dt <- data.table(x=c(1,NA,3),y=c(2,NA,NA),z=c(3,NA,1))
> dt
    x  y  z
1:  1  2  3
2: NA NA NA
3:  3 NA  1
> w <- apply(dt,1,which.min)
> w
[[1]]
x 
1 

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
z 
3 

> v <- unlist(lapply(w,function(z) ifelse(length(z)==0, NA, z[1])))
> v
[1]  1 NA  3
> dt$idx <- v
> dt
    x  y  z idx
1:  1  2  3   1
2: NA NA NA  NA
3:  3 NA  1   3
```

As you can see, the main reason for inelegance is that `apply` creates a list rather than an array. This happens because results have different length for each row. Also, I am invoking base-R functions `which.min`, `apply`, `unlist`, and `lapply`. *Is there a compact `data.table` way to get the desired result?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using .SD

```
d[, idx := apply(.SD, 1, which.min), .SDcols = c('x', 'y', 'z')]
```

However all NA rows would be blank; actually, as 2nd row is all NA, which.min would return `integer(0)`, so that the result of `apply` is of unequal length and d$idx is a list (second element of which is a zero-length vector);

```
   > d
    x  y  z idx
1:  1  2  3   1
2: NA NA NA    
3:  3 NA  1   3

> d$idx
[[1]]
x 
1 

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
z 
3
```

So to handle zero-length vectors and set return to NA in those cases;

```
d[, idx := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) which.min(x)[1] ), .SDcols = c('x', 'y', 'z')]
> d$idx
[1]  1 NA  3
```

Comment: I think the blank represent an empty list in the first case. It also looks like an entire column is of the list class. This may be a problem if someone wants to write.csv. The second option is also taking care of this annoyance. Still, is there a shorter way to write the second option?

Comment: @user3605620. yes, the first way would add a column of list.  I have edited the answer.

Comment: write a custom `which.min` function externally would make this line shorter. I couldn't think of any other way. :(

Comment: I think the best way would be to use `max.col` and `rowSums` with akrun's NA^x trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39275278/ Of course, that still not a "data.table way" like the OP wanted, but they should probably be using a matrix or reshaping their data here. Some more examples: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3732271+NA+rowsums+max.col

Comment: I have reasons to avoid using a matrix or reshaping. Also, data.table is one of the most efficient library for data manipulation. From akrun's answer, a slightly shorter way is `d[, idx := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) which.min(x)[1] ), .SDcols = c('x', 'y', 'z')]`

Comment: @user3605620. Sure, akun's way is more concise!

Comment: @user3605620 - data.table is not efficient just because. If you're using `apply` and looping over each row you're probably throwing most of the efficiencies out the window.